# How can I show continue reading option in blog app?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a blog app. In that there will be a lots of post in recycler view. Now all blogs are so long with lots of images and it's description.

What I want is in my main activity inside recyclerview, I need to show all post with it's header image and a bit descriptiom, and if user want to read more, then it should be show **continue reading** option/button and in that click of whole post sould be expand there only.

How can I do that?

I know recycler view and adapter stuff. but how I do this continue reading n all?

adapter row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/small_item_back"
    android:layout_height="100dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image5"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:text="Meals for One"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/iv_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would recommend you not to expand the recycler view there itself. Because Blogs are gonna be a long one and it will make a bad user experience. It's better to open the blog details in a new fragment or activity (whichever fits best to you)

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi Can you please post an example with Recycler view?

Comment: This app can be useful. It's not open-sourced but you get some idea.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dottedcircle.paper&ah=akHdN4j-hWnQe3_deoL7MYvhT2g

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spannable` text for this. i.e. in kotlin you can do it like below in your recyclerview adapter.

```
if (yourText.length > 60) {
    val spanText =

        SpannableString("${mList[position].eventDetailsInfo!!.substring(0, 50)} see more...")
        spanText.setSpan(
          ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY),
          spanText.length - 12,
          spanText.length - 1,
          Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
       )
       yourViewHolder.tv.text = spanText
    }
```

Then in `onclick` of your view item you can set full description in `textview`.

Comment: Can you please post complete  example?

Comment: I would like to highlight a few things. This can be useful if the blog is text descriptive. What if blogs contain images and other stuff?

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi yes, that particular blog post when user clock to expand option it obviously contains images and description.

Comment: you will do this code in onBindViewHolder(). I think you understand

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside onBindViewHolder of your recyclerview.. 
getlineCount() will return you the total number of lines. you can specify maximum lines to display inside MAX_LINES. Use ellipsize property to end. 
here content is my textview.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MovieReviewViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //get the current review
        Review review = reviewList.get(position);
        //update view data
        holder.author.setText(review.getAuthor());
        holder.content.setText(review.getContent());

        //get the total line count for the review TextView and set the maxlines accordingly
        // to expand and collapse cardview wrapping the review content
        holder.content.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int lineCount = holder.content.getLineCount();

                if (lineCount > MAX_LINES) {
                    //initially display the content in the set max number of lines
                    holder.content.setMaxLines(MAX_LINES);
                    holder.content.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                    //show a button to enable expanding truncated text
                    holder.button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    //set click listener on the "show more" button
                    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (expandable) {
                                expandable = false;
                                //extent the max lines to be able to display the whole review content
                                //if "show more" is clicked
                                holder.content.setMaxLines(lineCount);
                                holder.button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up);
                            } else {
                                expandable = true;
                                //reset the max lines when "show less" is clicked
                                holder.content.setMaxLines(MAX_LINES);
                                holder.button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down);
                            }

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    //hide the button if the review content lines is not more than the set max lines property
                    holder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```